# Update charts during ActiveSheet.Calculate

Tags: excel, vba

**Some Background:** I have a table of counts which is graphed. When slicers are changed I need to click Calculate to update the counts and graph. (Calculation is set to manual due to workbook size).
Believe it or not, using the calculate button is beyond some users.. I would like to have it as a form button easily visible next to the graph.
I used the Macro recorder to find the statement for Calculate Sheet.
It gave me ActiveSheet.Calculate.

**Problem:** When I run ActiveSheet.Calculate from my macro button the graphs on the sheet do not update. Excel's calculate button, however, works. Surely they are functionally identical? Why does my button not update but Excel's calculate does?

When I change the button to use Application.Calcluate, the graphs update.

Comment: It happens in case of graphs when we set calculate option to manual. Check the following URL: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/cant-get-charts-to-update-when-in-manual/fadc5f1a-69ec-45bb-b555-f22cd31f94d9

Answer (score 1):

Well, on my version of Excel (2010), there are two Calculate buttons: Calculate Now <kbd>F9</kbd> and Calculate Sheet <kbd>Shift-F9</kbd>. Calculate Now re-calculates the whole Workbook and should be functionally identical to `Application.Calculate`, whereas Calculate Sheet only recalculates the individual worksheet and should be functionally identical to `ActiveSheet.Calculate`.

I would suggest using the `Workbook.RefreshAll` method or the `WorkbookConnection.Refresh` method before the `ActiveSheet.Calculate` to see if that has less overhead than the `Application.Calculate` method.

Oh, and I can definitely believe using the calculate button is beyond some users.